# On boarding need to click two time the azure consent page.

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, oauth

We are using azure AD and Auth0 for out application While Onboarding new tenant some time we need to click two times the azure consent page.

[image]

Comment: This isn't really a question that can be answered here. You should create a support ticket with MSFT for support issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. we have already raise the ticket with MSFT.

Comment: Awesome. Hopefully they can resolve it!